# Why would Becky send the drone to the diner?

Tags: plot-explanation, fall

In the 2022 movie *Fall*: seeing as the girls established that there was mobile phone reception at - or near - the base of the tower, why would Becky attempt to send the drone with note attached all the way to the diner several miles away?

Flying the drone with a mobile phone attached to the base of the tower has, I believe, a better chance of success.
Plus the distance covered allows for repeated attempts.
It's 2000 ft to the base and several miles to the diner, so I dare say the latter, chosen option was always going to be a one-way trip.

> Keep in mind that a mobile phone sent to the base of the tower via another means provides the ultimate salvation.

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB for the edit and the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was really just a Maguffin meant to add despair to the situation.  If anything, it was a tell-tale statement that Becky was alone, because anyone else would have seen the trailer coming and warned Becky to maneuver over it, while Becky was focused solely on the Drone screen.  They were in the desert, there were no trees to block the view of the oncoming trailer.